# Interaction of POSIX file descriptors and C FILEs

Tags: c, file, posix, file-descriptor

I'm reading the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_05.html) and I can't fully understand how file descriptors, file descriptions and streams interact.

```
FILE* f1 = fopen("a.txt", "r");
int fno = fileno(f1);
FILE* f2 = fdopen(fno, "r");

// is it true?
assert(fileno(f2) == fno);

// does it close only f1 or f2 too?
fclose(f1);
fgetc(f2); // valid?
```

(Question is in the comments.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C standard library gives you the opaque pointer `FILE*`, a *file handle*, which you can manipulate with `fopen()`/`fclose()`, and access with `fread()`/`fwrite()`.

POSIX offers a notion of *file descriptors* which are integers. You can manipulate those with `open()`/`close()`, and access with `read()`/`write()`.

For every open file handle `FILE * fp` on a POSIX system, you can get the underlying file descriptor with `fileno(fp)`. Conversely, for an existing file descriptor `n`, you can open a standard file handle with `fdopen(n)`.

In other words, the POSIX file descriptors are an operating system primitive which is used to *implement* the C standard io library. Note that POSIX file descriptors also serve as handles for sockets.

Your final call to `fgets()` is undefined because the `fclose()` invalidates the file handle, and consequently its underlying file descriptor. `fdopen()` does *not* duplicate the file descriptor.

Comment: Does it imply that I can call `fdopen` on each file descriptor at most once?

Comment: If the file descriptor is also in use by some other `FILE *`, then you cannot reliably call `fdopen()` even once - because you can only reliably call `fclose()` on one of the two `FILE *`; you cannot reliably use `fclose()` on the second.  If you used `dup()` or perhaps `dup2()` before using `fdopen()`, you could use `fdopen()` as often as the O/S will let you before you run out of file descriptors.

Comment: And besides freeing resources I'd anticipate puzzling influences of buffering.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true and it closes both files as they use the same file descriptor.

Comment: But then how the second `f2` is freed (the FILE structure)? I guess I can't call `fclose(f2)` on it anymore, right?

Comment: Well, I don't know ;-) Probably `fdopen` allocates the new `FILE` object which is to be freed, but closing it is a bit too late. I think you'd still have to call `fclose`, though it may fail. I'd recommend against having to `FILE` objects pointing to the same descriptor. If you actually need that, duplicated the file handle. like `fdopen(dup(fileno(f1)),..)`

Comment: `f2` is _not_ freed. Instead, it simply contains a stale file descriptor that has been closed. If you try to use `f2` your application should <strike>crash</strike> (return an error) -- assuming you haven't opened another file with the same file descriptor yet. Never mix Standard C IO with POSIX IO on the same file, it'll lead to misery. :)